# Como se deve importar matplotlib._cntr utilizando A versão LTS (2.2.0) do Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Para construir arquivos GeoJson, utiliza-se o módulo ._cntr

```
import matplotlib._cntr as cntr
```

Ao tentar carregá-lo usando o matplotlib 2.2.0 ele devolve erro:

> ```
> ImportError: No module named _cntr
> ```

Como esse módulo deve ser importado?
As versões mais antigas do matplotlib permitem o carregamento, especialmente a 2.1.0 a anterior LTS.

Comment: Nosso idioma oficial é o **Português**. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Não encontrei quase nada sobre esse modulo. Ele parece ser [não documentado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304722/python-find-contour-lines-from-matplotlib-pyplot-contour). Olhei no site e não a nada disponivel com este nome. Não existe outro modulo similar?

Comment: Oi @Guto realmente não tem descrição do módulo, pois ele é a implementação do método, como toda função iniciada com `_`
Minha intenção é descobrir qual a forma de importar isso na versão atual do matplotlib

Comment: De uma olhada [nestas opcões](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349730/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-cntr). Eu não tenho mais ideias, não consegui encontrar mais mencões a isso no matplotlib.

Comment: Valeu @Guto o pessoal no Github me respondeu que esse módulo foi implementado e que foi descontinuado no Matplotlib, o Benjamin Root está dando segmento a essas funções, através do código https://github.com/matplotlib/legacycontour

Answer (score 1):

O Código foi descontinuado do Matplotlib, por conta de algumas particularidades para resolver as funções de contour e contourf (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10709).
Entretanto, algumas soluções estão sendo reaproveitadas pelo contribuidor Benjamin Root, através do Repositório: https://github.com/matplotlib/legacycontour